# Excluding a blob column from active record/linq query results

Tags: subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

What's the easiest way to exclude a column from the result set in a Subsonic/ActiveRecord/Linq query?

I've a got a table of images, and often I only want the meta data associated with the image (image id/name/dimensions for example).  Seems fairly wasteful to be pulling in the entire image data for these requests.

My current thought is to split out the image data to a separate table, but I'm wondering if there's an easier/better way.

Answer (score 0):

As You can see in the docs via the link below its possible to use LINQ and detail your query that way.

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord

Comment: I can't see anything in those docs about excluding columns from an active record query.  The best I've come up with so far is using a CodingHorror query with ExecuteTypedList.